# How do I restrict user from inputting non-numeric characters?

Tags: c, loops, user-input

Hi please take a look on this code:

```
while (cont == 1) {
    ...

    scanf_s("%d", &input);

    if (0 < input <= 5){
        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            printf("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("3");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("4");
            break;
        case 5:
            cont = 0;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong input !");
            break;
        }

    }else{
        printf("Error, Not a number !");
    }
}
```

If I input something that is not a number, it results in an infinite loop. How do I restrict char inputs?

Comment: You can't stop users entering bogus data.  You can only detect that they have done so and respond to the erroneous input.

Comment: Always check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: A usually simpler way to handle invalid input is to read the whole line (using e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) and then use `sscanf` to attempt to parse the input.

Comment: You should take a look on condition examples: `if (0 < input <= 5)` This will not do what you expect. What you want is `if (0 < intput && input <= 5)`

Comment: I am not able to understand question.Specifically  "it will show infinite loop", what does it means?

Comment: Why not remove the `switch()` completely and simply `printf ("%d", input);`? With a proper conditional of `if (0 < intput && input <= 5)` your `default` case will never be reached. You could include just one additional test for `if (input == 5) cont = 0;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hi, im calling a different function for each case actually. that's not the actual code.

Comment: @Vagish hi, there are some printf before the scanf_s("%d", &input), it will loop those printfs if i input characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if(scanf_s("%d", &input) != 1) {
    printf("Wrong input !");
    break;
}
```

You should ALWAYS check the return value of `scanf_s` anyway.

Comment: Thanks ! but it stops the program completely. how do I loop back to the "while(cont == 1)" again ?

Comment: Just skip the break

Answer (score 0):

After the `scanf_s()` fails, you need to read at least one character (the character that it failed on); usually, it makes most sense to discard the rest of the line that the user entered:

```
while (cont == 1) {
    int rc;

    ...

    if ((rc = scanf_s("%d", &input)) < 0)
    {
        printf("EOF detected\n");
        break;
    }
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ;
        printf("Error, Not a number!\n");
        continue;     
    }

    if (0 < input <= 5){
        switch (input) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            printf("%d", input);
            break;
        case 5:
            cont = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input (1-5 required)!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If EOF is detected in the 'gobble' loop, you could detect EOF there and repeat the print and break the loop immediately.  OTOH, the next `scanf_s()` should also report EOF, so it isn't 100% necessary.  It depends a little on where the prompting occurs; if you get EOF, you probably shouldn't prompt again, so maybe the test after the inner while loop should be:

```
if (c == EOF)
{
    printf("EOF detected\n");
    break;
}
else
{
    printf("Error, not a number\n");
    continue;
}
```

You can play with variants of the 'gobble' loop that read up to a newline or a digit, and use `ungetch(c, stdin);` to return the digit to the input stream for the next call to `scanf_s()` to process — you probably wouldn't prompt for more input if you're going to process the already entered digit (that would confuse).

There are endless other games you can play.  One option to consider is limiting the number of failed inputs before you give up — if the user hasn't entered a valid number in 10 tries, they probably aren't going to.

Note how the error processing tells the user what the valid range of numbers is; that helps them get it right.  Also notice that the messages have a newline at the end; that's generally a good idea. In contexts outside interactive I/O, the newline can help ensure that the output appears when it is printed, not some arbitrary time later when some other print adds a newline, or the output buffer fills up and the pending data is flushed after all.